# Performance testing on Client-Server desktop App

Tags: performance-testing, desktop-application, load-testing

I am trying to implement load tests on a desktop app.

1. This application is client-server written in c#.
2. The server side is an SQL DB.
3. Multiple clients run in parallel from different computers.
4. The network traffic is TDS over TCP/IP.

I would like to make load tests with multiple users, asserting the time to complete operations with different amount of users, and I don't know which tool to use.

I tried with JMETER but I think it can not record the traffic and replicate it.

Comment: I solved it by getting transactions that the client makes to the db in difretent operations (with a log that the client generate), and then use JDBC samplers in JMETER with these transactions.